# Array - Select the sub children id's from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array built from a function that sorts allowed or valid url slugs and their ids into another array. I can call the current category id by passing the url slug to the category. Now I need to get the children category ids (if any) so i can call the appropriate items from the database for display purpose.

Heres an example of the array:

```
Array (
    [radios] => 1
    [radios/motorola] => 2
    [radios/motorola/handheld] => 3
    [radios/motorola/mobile] => 4
    [radios/icom] => 5
    [radios/icom/handheld] => 6
    [radios/icom/mobile] => 7
    [radios/mics-and-speakers] => 8
    [radios/mounts] => 9
    [radios/radio-other] => 10
    [misc] => 11
    [misc/led] => 12
    [phones] => 13
    [phones/samsung] => 14
    [phones/lg] => 15
    [phones/motorola] => 16
    [phones/huawei] => 17
    [phones/blackberry] => 18
    [phones/flip] => 19
    [boosters] => 20
    [boosters/standalone] => 21
    [boosters/indoor-antenna] => 22
    [boosters/outdoor-antenna] => 23
    [boosters/connections] => 24
    [accessories] => 25
    [accessories/cases] => 26
    [accessories/other] => 27
    [internet] => 28
    [internet/fusion] => 29
    [internet/point-to-point] => 30
    [internet/hotspots] => 31
    [internet/gateways] => 32
    [internet/switches] => 33
    [cameras] => 34
    [cameras/complete-kits] => 35
    [cameras/additional-cameras] => 36
    [cameras/other] => 37
);
```

As you can see, each result points to the category ID of that group. If i visit the following url:

```
http://example.com/store/cameras
```

I can print out that `THE PATH CURRENTLY IS: 34` which is correct. Since It has children under it, I also need their ID's and the ID's of any of their children, etc etc. That way on `radios`, i can show ALL of the sub category items, and on `radios/motorola` i am only showing the Motorola based items and its children, and such down the line.

If there an easy way, using this array I have now, to sort the children (if any) all the way down and get back just their id's (preferably in a new array) for showing database items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a function like this to filter your array,

```
function filterArray($array, $term) {   
    $pattern = "/\b" . str_replace($term, '/', '\/') . "\b/i";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(preg_match($pattern, $key)) {
            /* Following condition makes sure that your search
            will match starting from the beginning. */          
            if (stripos(trim($key), $term) === 0){
                $filtred[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Then call the above function with the `$array` and your search `$term`.

`filterArray($array, 'radios')` will give you this,

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )

`filterArray($array, 'radios/motorola')` will give you this,

> Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 )

And so on.. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe try double layer array, so that you can store values like this,

```
Array (
[name] => John
[surname] => Smith
[contact] => Array ( 
                    [address] => 18 Maple Street
                    [number] => 555 477 77 77
                    )
)
```

This way if you need to print something from "contact" you can use a loop and print all childs of contact field.

Comment: ..what? How does that help get children ids from an array branch? I already have an array with the ids I need, I just need to link the children ids so I can get products from their ids